# How to customize Doctrine Inheritance Type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a parent entity and many inherited entity with `JOINED` strategy.
in `Doctrine` when i want to update or select some row of child table doctrine create heavy query with `inner join`.

parent class:

```
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
abstract class Parent {
    //..
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\childRepository")
 */
class Child extends Parent {
    //..
}
```

I want to remove inner join that automatically generated in create query builder inside of my repository class. 
also `findBy()` or `findOneBy()` if it can.

In my repository class:

```
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

class ChildRepository extends ParentRepository {

    public function getAllBySomeQuery() {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('child');

        //...
    }
}
```

That was a sample of generated query:

> SELECT ch.some_field FROM child_entity ch INNER JOIN parent_entity parent1 ON ch.id = parent1.id

I temporary solved this problem with change `JOINED` strategy to `SINGLE_TABLE` but this cause me other problem that not related to this question.

**How can i doing nested join instead of using `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('child')` inside my repository class? or how to create view from database and pass it to doctrine in best way.**

Comment: Changing the `@InheritanceType` is not simply something you can do on a whim, it is dependent on your table structure.  What is your structure?  If you have a base table and each child has its own table, you have to use `JOINED`.  If it's a single table for all of the entities, use `SINGLE_TABLE`.  For the JOINED strategy you're going to have JOINs: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#id3

Comment: @JasonRoman Tnx Jason. yes you right. my structure is one base table and each child has its own table in database as i describe in question. I change inheritance type because at least three inner join was executed per any related request to child table and this can really heavy cost for server performance in big data. I change inheritance type just for temporary solution.

Comment: JOINs on their own aren't necessarily expensive; databases are built for that.  But yes they are more expensive than joining a single table.  Three INNER JOINs sounds like a lot and I'm not sure why that would be happening, would have to see the entities and what's happening.

Comment: @JasonRoman That was happened because i must to join a child entity in other child entity. something like this: **in child repository 1** i join to **child 2**.